How to return count number from a wordpress database
I have a database 'wp_db7_forms', with fields, 'form_id', 'form_post_id' and 'form_date'.
I am trying to get a COUNT of the number of entries for a specific 'form_post_id'.
With this sql query in phpmyadmin
SELECT COUNT(form_id) FROM `wp_db7_forms` WHERE form_post_id=8420 LIMIT 0, 500;

I get the output expected of 6 entries
When I create the php query in phpmyadmin and copy and paste this into a shortcode snippet I get nothing!
Or sometimes I can get an error in formating and syntax for the one line of SELECT COUNT FROM WHERE.
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(form_id) FROM`wp_db7_forms` WHERE form_post_id=8420 LIMIT 0, 500;";
echo "the number is" $results; 
?>

I keep getting an error that says check my syntax for the MariaDB SELECT COUNT FROM WHERE.  I've tried changing so many things I am now befuddled. I have read many pages too, but have been unable to succeed. I am 77 and finding this hard learning. I have created a couple of queries for entry into the webpages, but this one has beat me.
Can anyone please help?
Found an answer after being pointed in the right direct.
<?php

    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_db7_forms WHERE form_post_id=8420 ");
echo "<p>User count is {$user_count}</p>";


Looks like there's a space missing between FROM and \wp_db7_forms``. Try fixing that first.

Highly recommend you build you SQL statement in a $wbdb->prepare first for security.

It is recommended to use the $wpdb->get_var() method when retrieving a count of rows. This method will return the count directly, rather than inside of an array or object like wpdb::get_results().

Thanks for the link.  All now working well.
show_errors();
    $user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_db7_forms WHERE form_post_id=8420 ");
echo "User count is {$user_count}";